# getting permission denied error while trying to add certificate in pod/container

Tags: c#, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi, kubernetes-pod, docker-container

I am using below code to add certificate in pod/container's certificate root store,

```
 var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText("/etc/secret/certfile")));
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(new X509Certificate2(cert));
            store.Close();
```

But getting below error,

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The X509 certificate could not be added to the store.
> ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/root' is denied.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

I have below docker file which I am using,

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-alpine
 RUN apk upgrade -U
 EXPOSE 5000 7000
 ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY . /app
 USER guest
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test.Web.dll"]
```

Comment: There are issues with permissions to access certificates store within the container. Is it required to build an image with `USER guest`? If not, you can remove `USER guest` or define `root` - `USER root`.

Comment: thanks. could you please give some example docker file

Comment: Since by default user in container is `root`, you should remove this line `USER guest` in your docker file and then re-build the image.

Comment: This worked for me. The problem was that scaffolding a containerized app with visual studio is setting `USER app` per default. removing that line works.